# Wordpress permissions issue - register_post_type()

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

When adding a custom post type via the `register_post_type()` to a pre-existing menu, the editing page (`wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=locations`) is not permissible to view- error message shown: `You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page.`

However, using the main admin menu (i.e. `'show_in_menu' = true`) allows for the page fine.

**Note: administrators account being used; the link is created and visible with both methods, I would like for the custom post type to be accessible via a pre-existing menu** `cms`

The code used is as follows:

```
register_post_type("location", array(
    "labels" => array("name" => "Locations", "singular_name" => "Location"),
    "show_ui" => true,
    "show_in_admin_bar" => true,
    "show_in_menu" => "admin.php?page=cms", // => true : works as main menu item
    "supports" => array('title'),
    "show_in_nav_menus" => false,
    "has_archive" => false,
    "public" => true
));
```

Hopefully somebody can shed some light on the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You probably are not using the `init` action. Also you named your post type *Locations* but it is not allowed to use capitals in post type names.

your `show_in_menu` is also invalid.

```
functions locations(){
  register_post_type("locations", array(
    "labels" => array("name" => "Locations", "singular_name" => "Location"),
    "show_ui" => true,
    "show_in_nav_menus" => false,
    "show_in_admin_bar" => true,
    "supports" => array('title'),

    // Not allowed to view, link is created as sub-menu item
    "show_in_menu" => "cms"
    // Allowed to view, link is created as main menu item
    "show_in_menu" => true
  ));   
}
add_action( 'init', 'locations' );
```

There are to many small errors. You should check the example in the [codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/register_post_type)

Comment: It is being called via the `init` hook; and capitalisation was fixed earlier but isn't the issue. What is the invalid nature of `show_in_menu`?

Comment: Did you read the codex? http://codex.wordpress.org/register_post_type#Arguments The part about `show_in_menu`

Comment: Indeed I did. `cms` was shortened from `admin.php?page=cms` - sorry for not mentioning. I'll update the preview code.